# ActiveMQ 5.10: Cannot restrict access to server from remote client

Tags: security, connection, activemq-classic, restrict

I install ActiveMQ 5.10 on MacOSX Yosemite.
I can change the file jetty-realm.properties to restrict access to Web Console at localhost:8161.

However, when I write Ruby code to connect to the ActiveMQ using Stomp like this:

```
require 'stomp'
client = Stomp::Client.new('any username', 'any password', 'localhost', 61613)
```

I can use the client to publish and subscribe to every queue on ActiveMQ server.

Can somebody please suggest a way that I can restrict the access to ActiveMQ server from remote connections.

I have tried the following links, but none of them works:
    https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/how-to-secure-a-activemq
    http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html#Version5GettingStarted-ConfiguringActiveMQ
    http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after playing awhile more and read the whole schema file for broker.

In ActiveMQ 5.10, the broker is put directly in **conf/activemq.xml**.

First, I solve the problem like this: In activemq.xml, under `<broker>`, I put:

```
<plugins> 
  <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
    <users>
      <authenticationUser username="admin" password="password" groups="admins,publishers,consumers"/>
    </users>
  </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

So it was the missing `<plugins>` in all the dumb documentations that made the config be useless.

Better solution:

I copy the whole `<broker>` section in **activemq.xml** and place it in a file called **broker.xml** (You can call it anything, for example **apache_dumb_documentation.xml**), under a section called `<bean>`

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

  <broker>
    ... broker config here, including <plugins> ...
  </broker>

</beans>
```

Then in activemq, in the former place of `<broker>`, I just write:

```
<import resource="broker.xml"/>
```